# Jquery keyup then next()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keydown, keyup

I have a form that is split into individual input boxes that visitors type letters into that form a complete word. Each input has a max length attribute of 1 that is caught by `keyup()`, then if the input length equals 1 it goes to the next input using next().

This system works fine, **BUT** people are complaining that when they type fast it will miss letters. I am curious to know if this is simply a delay in the `next()` function that cannot be overcome, or if this is just bad coding on my part?

Here is a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/873f4Lo0/)**, and here is a runnable Stack Snippet:

```js
$('#psw input').keyup(function(e) {
  if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, 1));
  }
  if ($(this).val().length == $(this).attr("maxlength")) {
    if ($(this).next('[type="text"]').length > 0) {
      $(this).next('[type="text"]')[0].focus();
    }
  }
});

$('#psw input').keydown(function(e) {
  if ((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && $(this).val() == '') {
    if ($(this).prev('[type="text"]').length > 0) {
      $(this).prev('[type="text"]')[0].focus();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="psw">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
</div>
```

Comment: Not necessarily bad, but I can see how a user typing very quickly could overwhelm the system.  If you wanted to get really complex, you could trap $(document).keyup and keep your own buffer of keystrokes.  Then the user could type as fast as they want, but what they see might be delayed a bit...

Comment: a quick comment on your code, the nested `if` statements, shouldn't they be if(condition1 && condition2)?

Comment: that is for mobile browsers that do not honour MAXLENGTH, it checks to see if the input has more than 1 character, if so removes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that users typing quickly will usually have multiple keys pressed at the same time, so when you rely on `keyup`, you get inconsistent results, because the user will have pressed a second key by the time they have released the first.

Here is a modified version of your function that uses `keydown` only, along with `setTimeout` to let the character in the current field be deleted when the user presses backspace, before jumping to the previous field. This works because `setTimeout` queues the field movement command after the user's backspace key is executed in the browser execution queue. No key buffer or anything else complex is needed.

This eliminates all of the issues with keys being pressed soon after one another. Try it while typing fast!

**Live Demo:**

```js
$('#psw input').keydown(function(e) {
  if ((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46)) {
    if ($(this).prev('[type="text"]').length > 0) {
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).prev('[type="text"]')[0].focus();
      }, 0);
    }
    return;
  }

  if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, 1));
  }
  if ($(this).val().length == $(this).attr("maxlength")) {
    if ($(this).next('[type="text"]').length > 0) {
      $(this).next('[type="text"]')[0].focus();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="psw">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input type="text" maxlength="1">
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/873f4Lo0/2/

Comment: little confused what the var bsp is for?

Comment: @AndrewWard Accidentally left that var in, it's not needed. I've edited it out of my answer.

Comment: I've just come to realise by using keydown instead of keyup, it no longer focuses on the next input box after typing a letter, instead it jumps to the next once another key is pushed, whereas keyup would allow the letter to be sent, then focus on the next empty input box. Small issue, but causes problems on mobile because you have to type the letter twice for it to focus on the next input.